# Undefined method for model in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In a view, I have the following code:

```
<%= Photo.where(user_token: @token) %>
```

which returns:

```
#<Photo::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fee45353ac8>
```

and if I add .inspect

```
#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Photo id: 420, photo_url: "Screen_Shot_2015-01-03_at_1.11.25_AM.png", created_at: "2015-02-03 02:06:28", updated_at: "2015-02-03 02:06:28", user_token: "gila-2">]>
```

but if I do:

```
<%= Photo.where(user_token: @token).photo_url %>
```

I get `undefined method photo_url for <Photo::ActiveRecord_Relation`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `ActiveRecord::Relation` can represent many records if more than one record qualifies for the `where` condition.  Try something like:

```
<%= Photo.where(user_token: @token).first.photo_url %>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to load the first record that matches the query use the `find_by` method:

```
Photo.find_by(user_token: @token)
```

That method returns just one record (or `nil`if not found). Whereas `where` returns a relation that (simplified!) works like an array.